# What mean $|Y_n(t)|\leq 1+|X_n(t)|$ where $X_n=(X_n(t))$ is a stochastic process

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X_n=(X_n(t))_{t\in [0,T]}$ a stochastic process. Let $Y_n=(Y_n(t))_{t\in [0,T]}$ a random process. What does $$|Y_n(t)|\leq 1+|X_n(t)|,$$
for all $t$ and all $n$.

1) Does it mean
$$\mathbb P(|Y_n(t)|\leq 1+|X_n(t)|)=1$$
for all $n$ and all $t$, or $$\mathbb P(\forall t,\forall n, |Y_n(t)|\leq 1+|X_n(t)|)=1\ \ ?$$

Comment: Okay $n\in \mathbb N$, right? I would say the first one. However one needs to specify what kind of process one is dealing with when saying these kind of things. Cadlag? Or Continuous? I believe (I'm not sure), for instance, if your process is continuous in $t$ then the two statements you said are equivalent, so it doesn't matter what one means.

Comment: No sorry, yes $n\in \mathbb N$...